# Swift 5.4 hex to NSColor

Tags: swift, macos, hex, nscolor

I am developing a program for macOS.

I need to convert a hex color to NSColor.

I looked at the proposed solutions here:

[Convert Hex Color Code to NSColor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8697205/convert-hex-color-code-to-nscolor)

[How to convert hex to NSColor?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430275/how-to-convert-hex-to-nscolor)

But none of it works correctly with Xcode 12.5.1.

At the moment I did this, it works correctly:

```swift
extension NSObject {
    func RGB(r:CGFloat, g:CGFloat, b:CGFloat, alpha:CGFloat? = 1) -> NSColor {
        return NSColor(red: r/255, green: g/255, blue: b/255, alpha: alpha!)
    }
}

let fillColor = RGB(r: 33, g: 150, b: 243)
```

Possibly not having to use Cocoa.

I would like a function like this: `hexToNSColor("#2196f3")`

Can you give me a hand?

Comment: Never forget to convert first to RGB colorspace (code in links doesn't do it)

Comment: the question is hex TO NSColor NOT get hex FROM NSColor as the quoted answer.

Comment: @Paul, I have a possible answer but cannot post it here, since "they" closed it. 
Ask another question, like: "Swift 5.4 hex to NSColor NOT hex value from NSColor in cocoa"

Comment: hey looks like I can reopen the question, and post my answer. Hope it helps after all that.

Comment: @workingdog I missed that. You have my upvote for answer. But this is a frequent question and should have not been re-opened. Should have been commented with correct link as a duplicate. Beside it's UIColor vs NSColor. Even XCode can now suggest to fix this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27430275/how-to-convert-hex-to-nscolor

Comment: yes fair enough, however the original reason for closing the question was some link to getting hex value from NSColor in cocoa, which is not what the question is about.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you could try something like this:

EDIT: included toHex(alpha:), from code I probably got from the net somewhere many years ago.

EDIT3,4: included the case for #RRGGBBAA

EDIT 5: stripping blank spaces in the hex string, to make NSColor (hex:" # 2196f380 ") work as well.

```
extension NSColor {
    
 convenience init(hex: String) {
    let trimHex = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let dropHash = String(trimHex.dropFirst()).trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    let hexString = trimHex.starts(with: "#") ? dropHash : trimHex
    let ui64 = UInt64(hexString, radix: 16)
    let value = ui64 != nil ? Int(ui64!) : 0
    // #RRGGBB
    var components = (
        R: CGFloat((value >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
        G: CGFloat((value >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
        B: CGFloat((value >> 00) & 0xff) / 255,
        a: CGFloat(1)
    )
    if String(hexString).count == 8 {
        // #RRGGBBAA
        components = (
            R: CGFloat((value >> 24) & 0xff) / 255,
            G: CGFloat((value >> 16) & 0xff) / 255,
            B: CGFloat((value >> 08) & 0xff) / 255,
            a: CGFloat((value >> 00) & 0xff) / 255
        )
    }
    self.init(red: components.R, green: components.G, blue: components.B, alpha: components.a)
}

func toHex(alpha: Bool = false) -> String? {
    guard let components = cgColor.components, components.count >= 3 else {
        return nil
    }
    
    let r = Float(components[0])
    let g = Float(components[1])
    let b = Float(components[2])
    var a = Float(1.0)
    
    if components.count >= 4 {
        a = Float(components[3])
    }
    
    if alpha {
        return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255), lroundf(a * 255))
    } else {
        return String(format: "%02lX%02lX%02lX", lroundf(r * 255), lroundf(g * 255), lroundf(b * 255))
    }
}
}
 
    let nscol = NSColor(hex: "#2196f3")  // <-- with or without #
```

EDIT2:

you can do the same for UIColor, and for Color (with UIColor or NSColor):

```
extension Color {
    public init(hex: String) {
        self.init(UIColor(hex: hex))
    }

    public func toHex(alpha: Bool = false) -> String? {
        UIColor(self).toHex(alpha: alpha)
    }
}
```

Comment: I bet op will ask to fix this because it's not accepting NSColor(hex: "#2196f3")

Comment: yeah, looks like I picked the wrong question to try to answer today.

Comment: @workingdog: Perfect, some curiosities.
1) Writing this function using the ternary operator could there be problems?
The second part the one with `self.init` could be written using the ternary operator or better not.
Link: https://pastebin.com/RuiV5SLf

2) If you also want to consider `alpha` what can I do?

Comment: updated my answer with code for alpha. As for the ternary, I leave it as an exercise to try.

Comment: added a possible use of a ternary.

Comment: I am not understanding how I should use the toHex function.
I have something like this for example: `let fillColor = NSColor(hex: "#2196f380")`

Comment: Then why the value of: `lroundf (a * 255)`, the alpha value does not go from 0.0 to 1.0?
Do I remember badly?

Comment: your questions intrigued me to find an answer by modifying the code,
 then by chance I came across the original code (or something similar) on the net at:
 https://cocoacasts.com/from-hex-to-uicolor-and-back-in-swift/

Currently my code only supports the RGB colors (#RRGGBB), as can be seen from the code, 
the alpha component is set to 1 in init(hex: Int). It would not take much to include 
the alpha component. I'm sure you can figure this one out.

However the toHex(alpha: true) returns the hex of a given NSColor when it includes an alpha component.

Comment: updated the answer to include the case #RRGGBBAA. It would be good if someone could test this.

Comment: I'm testing the code, but if I do this: `NSColor (hex:" # 2196f380 ")` seems to work without having to use toHex, right?

Comment: ok, fine. Updated my answer to cater for that case.

Comment: @workingdog Feel sorry for you. I feel you are being abused by op. He is back https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68739873/swift-convert-color-assets-to-nscolor

Comment: the revenge of the OP! and that's nothing, you should see this guy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68704749/dictation-speech-recognition-text-does-not-match-a-string-in-swift/68712250

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
 // With hash
 let color: NSColor = NSColor(hexString: "#ff8942")

 // Without hash, with alpha
 let secondColor: NSColor = NSColor(hexString: "ff8942", alpha: 0.5)

 // Short handling
 let shortColorWithHex: NSColor = NSColor(hexString: "fff")

 // From a real hex value (an `Int`)
 // With hash
 let color: NSColor = NSColor(hex: 0xff8942)

 // Without hash, with alpha
 let secondColor: NSColor = NSColor(hex: 0xff8942, alpha: 0.5)

*/

#if os(iOS) || os(tvOS) || os(watchOS)
import UIKit
typealias SWColor = UIColor
#else
import Cocoa
typealias SWColor = NSColor
#endif

private extension Int64 {
func duplicate4bits() -> Int64 {
    return (self << 4) + self
}
}

/// An extension of UIColor (on iOS) or NSColor (on OSX) providing HEX color handling.
public extension SWColor {
private convenience init?(hex3: Int64, alpha: Float) {
    self.init(red:   CGFloat( ((hex3 & 0xF00) >> 8).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat( ((hex3 & 0x0F0) >> 4).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
              blue:  CGFloat( ((hex3 & 0x00F) >> 0).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
              alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
}

private convenience init?(hex4: Int64, alpha: Float?) {
    self.init(red:   CGFloat( ((hex4 & 0xF000) >> 12).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat( ((hex4 & 0x0F00) >> 8).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
              blue:  CGFloat( ((hex4 & 0x00F0) >> 4).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0,
              alpha: alpha.map(CGFloat.init(_:)) ?? CGFloat( ((hex4 & 0x000F) >> 0).duplicate4bits() ) / 255.0)
}

private convenience init?(hex6: Int64, alpha: Float) {
    self.init(red:   CGFloat( (hex6 & 0xFF0000) >> 16 ) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat( (hex6 & 0x00FF00) >> 8 ) / 255.0,
              blue:  CGFloat( (hex6 & 0x0000FF) >> 0 ) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
}

private convenience init?(hex8: Int64, alpha: Float?) {
    self.init(red:   CGFloat( (hex8 & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat( (hex8 & 0x00FF0000) >> 16 ) / 255.0,
              blue:  CGFloat( (hex8 & 0x0000FF00) >> 8 ) / 255.0,
              alpha: alpha.map(CGFloat.init(_:)) ?? CGFloat( (hex8 & 0x000000FF) >> 0 ) / 255.0)
}

/**
 Create non-autoreleased color with in the given hex string and alpha.

 - parameter hexString: The hex string, with or without the hash character.
 - parameter alpha: The alpha value, a floating value between 0 and 1.
 - returns: A color with the given hex string and alpha.
 */
convenience init?(hexString: String, alpha: Float? = nil) {
    var hex = hexString

    // Check for hash and remove the hash
    if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
        hex = String(hex[hex.index(after: hex.startIndex)...])
    }

    guard let hexVal = Int64(hex, radix: 16) else {
        self.init()
        return nil
    }

    switch hex.count {
    case 3:
        self.init(hex3: hexVal, alpha: alpha ?? 1.0)
    case 4:
        self.init(hex4: hexVal, alpha: alpha)
    case 6:
        self.init(hex6: hexVal, alpha: alpha ?? 1.0)
    case 8:
        self.init(hex8: hexVal, alpha: alpha)
    default:
        // Note:
        // The swift 1.1 compiler is currently unable to destroy partially initialized classes in all cases,
        // so it disallows formation of a situation where it would have to.  We consider this a bug to be fixed
        // in future releases, not a feature. -- Apple Forum
        self.init()
        return nil
    }
}

/**
 Create non-autoreleased color with in the given hex value and alpha

 - parameter hex: The hex value. For example: 0xff8942 (no quotation).
 - parameter alpha: The alpha value, a floating value between 0 and 1.
 - returns: color with the given hex value and alpha
 */
convenience init?(hex: Int, alpha: Float = 1.0) {
    if (0x000000 ... 0xFFFFFF) ~= hex {
        self.init(hex6: Int64(hex), alpha: alpha)
    } else {
        self.init()
        return nil
    }
}

convenience init?(argbHex: Int) {
    if (0x00000000 ... 0xFFFFFFFF) ~= argbHex {
        let hex = Int64(argbHex)
        self.init(red: CGFloat( (hex & 0x00FF0000) >> 16 ) / 255.0,
                  green: CGFloat( (hex & 0x0000FF00) >> 8 ) / 255.0,
                  blue:  CGFloat( (hex & 0x000000FF) >> 0 ) / 255.0,
                  alpha: CGFloat( (hex & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) / 255.0)
    } else {
        self.init()
        return nil
    }
}

convenience init?(argbHexString: String) {
    var hex = argbHexString

    // Check for hash and remove the hash
    if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
        hex = String(hex[hex.index(after: hex.startIndex)...])
    }
    
    guard hex.count == 8, let hexVal = Int64(hex, radix: 16) else {
        self.init()
        return nil
    }
    self.init(red: CGFloat( (hexVal & 0x00FF0000) >> 16 ) / 255.0,
              green: CGFloat( (hexVal & 0x0000FF00) >> 8 ) / 255.0,
              blue:  CGFloat( (hexVal & 0x000000FF) >> 0 ) / 255.0,
              alpha: CGFloat( (hexVal & 0xFF000000) >> 24 ) / 255.0)
}

}
```