# Dictation (Speech Recognition) text does not match a string in Swift

Tags: swift, xcode, speech-recognition, speech-to-text

I have developed a speech recognition function that can detect **Arabic** audio and return a string, I assign it to a var called *speechRecogText*.

Within the code I also have a text field which I store the input in another string var called *textFieldText*.

**Goal** I want to be able to check if the *speechRecogText* contains wants in the *textFieldText*, this works normally with English but for Arabic it does not work.

However when I try the opposite way *speechRecogText.contains(textFieldText)* it works. Code below

```
    // the two variables
    var speechRecogText: String = ""
    var textFieldText: String = ""
```

Speech Recognition functions and Textfield... After I enter the inputs I call the function *compareTexts()*

```
func compareTexts() {
    
    // Checking the textField text
    if speechRecogText.contains(textFieldText) {
        print("matching texts")
    } else {
        print("not matching")
    }
    
    // Checking the speech recog text
    if textFieldText.contains(speechRecogText) {
        print("matching texts")
    } else {
        print("not matching")
    }
}
```

For example both would print word "قل" in Arabic. But when I call the function, the console shows (answer):

```
Console 
//matching texts
//not matching
```

I want the second one to also work/match and print matching texts.

Although both variables contain similar text the result is a bit confusing. Do they not store same values or is it they show the same stringa but deep in code they vary somehow?

I would really appreciate your support :)

Here is the entire code

This is the Entire Code.

```
import SwiftUI
import SwiftSpeech

struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var speechRecogText = "قل"
    @State var textFieldText = "قل"
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            
            //MARK: - Text Field
                        
            TextField("textfield text", text: $textFieldText)
                .padding()
            
            Button(action: {
                compareTexts()
            } ) {
                ZStack {
                    Color.blue.clipShape(Circle()).frame(width: 70, height: 70)
                    Text("Check").foregroundColor(.white)
                }
            }
            
            
            //MARK: - Speech Recognition
            
            
            Text("speechRecogText: " + speechRecogText)
            
            SwiftSpeech.RecordButton()
                .swiftSpeechRecordOnHold(locale: Locale(identifier: "ar"),
                                         animation: .spring(),
                                         distanceToCancel: 50)

                .onRecognizeLatest { result in
                    self.speechRecogText = result.bestTranscription.formattedString
                    if result.isFinal {
                        print("last transcript")
                    }
                } handleError: { error in
                    print("Failed recognizing the audio. Retry: \(error)")
                }
        }
        
    }
    

    func compareTexts() {
        // Checking the textField text
        if speechRecogText.contains(textFieldText) {
            print("---> speechRecogText contains textFieldText")
        } else {
            print("---> speechRecogText DOES NOT contains textFieldText")
        }

        // Checking the speech recog text
        if textFieldText.contains(speechRecogText) {
            print("---> textFieldText contains speechRecogText")
        } else {
            print("---> textFieldText DOES NOT contains speechRecogText")
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: could you give some more examples of arabic text where it does not work, because my test using your example arabic text works for me.

Comment: I tried a bunch of other words. They didn't work. Can you try just random words or short phrases?

Comment: If you think it will be better to share the speech recognition functions too, I will

Comment: no need for the speech function, just give me text that does not work. All the text I put in my tests work.

Comment: And you are using the same code? Can you share the code? Because honestly I have been trying different words and none are matching in the order I want.

Answer (score 1):

**Universal solution for any language**

I noticed that dictation actually appends a nil character, whose `unicodeScalar` is `65532` or `\u{fffc}`, to the string being processed, making the string unusable for searches. In Arabic it might become the first character because of the string direction.

```
extension String {
    func removeNilCharacters() -> String {
        return self.replacingOccurrences(of: "\u{fffc}", with: "", options: String.CompareOptions.literal, range: nil)
    }
}
```

Applying `.removeNilCharacters()` to the string returned by a textfield should resolve the issue, whether dictation was invoked or not.

Answer (score 0):

ok, this is how I tested comparing Arabic texts. It shows the expected results.

```
 import SwiftUI

@main
struct TestApp: App {
    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            ContentView()
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var results1 = "testing1"
    @State var results2 = "testing2"
    var speechRecogText: String = "قلّ"
    var textFieldText: String = "قلّ جسمه من الكبَر"
    
    func compareTexts() {
        // Checking the textField text
        if speechRecogText.trim().contains(textFieldText.trim()) {
            results1 = "speechRecogText contains textFieldText"
            print("---> speechRecogText contains textFieldText")
        } else {
            results1 = "speechRecogText DOES NOT contains textFieldText"
            print("---> speechRecogText DOES NOT contains textFieldText")
        }
        // Checking the speech recog text
        if textFieldText.trim().contains(speechRecogText.trim()) {
            results2 = "textFieldText contains speechRecogText"
            print("---> textFieldText contains speechRecogText")
        } else {
            results2 = "textFieldText DOES NOT contains speechRecogText"
            print("---> textFieldText DOES NOT contains speechRecogText")
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack (spacing: 50) {
            Text(results1)
            Text(results2)
        }
        .onAppear {
            compareTexts()
        }
    }
}

extension String {
    func trim() -> String {
        return self.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines)
    }
}
```

Comment: It is not working. Are you aware that the speechRecogText is from a speech recognition text (like dictation)?

Comment: The Console Prints ---> speechRecogText contains textFieldText
    ---> textFieldText DOES NOT contains speechRecogText

Comment: this is not the results I get. I get the correct results: ---> speechRecogText DOES NOT contains textFieldText
and ---> textFieldText contains speechRecogText. Can you tell us what systems you are using, what mac, ios, target you are setting. It is extremely unlikely that this would not work in other mac or ios.

Comment: could you also try to replace "contains" with "localizedCaseInsensitiveContains", see if this works for you.

Comment: It is a MacBook pro 13-inch, 2019, the development target is the latest 14.5 since in testing the functionality in the simple project. For the speech-to-text feature, I am using a third-party library called _SwiftSpeech_ for Speech Recognition. Here is the [link](https://github.com/Cay-Zhang/SwiftSpeech).

Comment: Can you share the whole project with me so I can test it and see if it is from my device or ...

Comment: I have given you the whole project in my answer. Are you saying this is not the code you are using to get the results.

Comment: In your example you have hard-coded the variables, my example I get the speech and convert it to text then assign that value to my speechRecogText

Comment: Your code works fine but it has no speech recognition method that assigns the value.

Comment: I see, you are having problems elsewhere in your code. 
Did my answer showed you that comparing Arabic text works?
This is what your goal was, is that correct?
You are saying you have a problem putting a string into a string variable. Show us the code you are using to do this.

Comment: Check the question again I have updated and added the entire code. Since .trim() didn't work I just removed it. You can think of it as the original code.

Comment: In your Button, before compareTexts(), could you add this line, and show me what the result is:
`print("speechRecogText: \(speechRecogText)  textFieldText: \(textFieldText)")`

Comment: Result: speechRecogText: ‏قل  textFieldText: قل

Comment: and with that you are telling me that the compareTexts() gives you the wrong results? Please show what the compareTexts() prints. I copy and pasted the text into my code and it works perfectly.

Comment: Full Result: speechRecogText: ‏قل  textFieldText: قل
---> speechRecogText contains textFieldText
---> textFieldText DOES NOT contains speechRecogText

Comment: This issue is kind of critical but very weird. Can you just share the project file with me and I will run your project to see the results?

Comment: my project file is the code in my answer nothing more. I copy and pasted the text you gave me, and it works perfectly. Can you put the trim() function like I have in my code to trim any blank spaces in the text. This is the text I put in: `var speechRecogText: String =  "قل"
    var textFieldText: String =  "قل"`

Comment: Are you using the third-part library too?

Comment: I am using the code that I have in my answer, nothing more. But you are not using the same code. Put the trim() function like I have in my code. Exactly like in my code. And tell me if it works.

Comment: Can you try this code. Make two text fields. One enters the word with the keyboard. the other use dictation and compare those two texts. Will you get the same results?

Comment: I suspect that "speechRecogText" maybe updating because you are not stopping the recording. To test that , 
in your "SwiftSpeech.RecordButton()" can you put this 

`.swiftSpeechToggleRecordingOnTap(locale: Locale(identifier: "ar"), animation: .spring())`

instead of "swiftSpeechRecordOnHold(...)" 
and make sure the recording is stopped (click the recording button again) 
before you click the "compareTexts()" button.

Comment: I figured it out. Check I gave an answer to my question :)

Answer (score 0):

So after testing the code I figured out that the speech recognition text had more characters than the hardcoded string. When I used .count() for the textField text "قل" it printed 2, but for the speech recognition, it had printed 3.

I used the mapping method to view the extra character.

```
speechRecogText.map({ print($0) })
```

It looked like the first character was an empty space. So I used

```
speechRecogText.removeFirst()
```

and then compared. And the result was as desired.

Comment: great, if you had used my .trim() and code in my answer, it would have worked a long time ago.

Comment: I used but for some reason, it didn't work. Maybe something was wrong when I was trying yours. But thank you a lot for the contribution and effort : )

Comment: thanks for reporting back. Can you use the trim function and let me know if this works now.

Comment: I checked it again with .count(), .map() and .contain(). But for some reason .trim() wasn't removing the empty spaces. Even if it is two words in a string.

Comment: However I am thankful. .removeFirst() worked!