# How to get a string from a CGColor MacOS

Tags: swift, xcode, macos, colors

I am trying to make an app to make it easier to select certain colors and for me to use the  `NSPasteboard.setString` command I need to format the color as a string. Is there a way I can change a CGColor into a string?
Thanks!

Comment: What would the string be, RRGGBBAA values?

Comment: Anything that shows the color really it could be that or something like `rgba(whatever)`

Comment: you could also try using hex to represent the color, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679658/swift-5-4-hex-to-nscolor/68680901

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a useful extension I made for doing this with `CGColor`. You can get the RGBA components, as well as convert them back.

Code:

```
extension CGColor {
    /// Components of a color. Contains `rgba`.
    struct Components: Codable {
        let red: CGFloat
        let green: CGFloat
        let blue: CGFloat
        let alpha: CGFloat

        init(red: CGFloat, green: CGFloat, blue: CGFloat, alpha: CGFloat) {
            self.red = red
            self.green = green
            self.blue = blue
            self.alpha = alpha
        }

        init?(rgba: [CGFloat]) {
            guard rgba.count == 4 else { return nil }

            red = rgba[0]
            green = rgba[1]
            blue = rgba[2]
            alpha = rgba[3]
        }

        var all: [CGFloat] {
            [red, green, blue, alpha]
        }
    }

    var components: Components? {
        var red: CGFloat = 0
        var green: CGFloat = 0
        var blue: CGFloat = 0
        var alpha: CGFloat = 0
        _ = NSColor(cgColor: self)?.getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)
        let components = [red, green, blue, alpha]
        return Components(rgba: components)
    }

    static func create(from components: Components) -> CGColor {
        self.init(
            red: components.red,
            green: components.green,
            blue: components.blue,
            alpha: components.alpha
        )
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
if let components = CGColor(red: 1, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1).components {
    print(components)
    let new = CGColor.create(from: components)
    print(new)
}
```

Prints: `Components(red: 1.0, green: 0.2, blue: 0.2, alpha: 1.0)`

Prints: `<CGColor 0x600003f1d500> [<CGColorSpace 0x600003f1ab80> (kCGColorSpaceICCBased; kCGColorSpaceModelRGB; Generic RGB Profile)] ( 1 0.2 0.2 1 )`

Comment: hmm, im getting these errors

`= UIColor(cgColor: self).getRed(&red, green: &green, blue: &blue, alpha: &alpha)` - cannot find UIColor in scope

`red: components.red,` - Cannot convert value of type 'double' to expected argument type 'CGFloat'

Comment: @TheAxolotlMan My bad, should be fixed now!

Comment: Strange. I'm still getting an error on `red: components.red,
green: components.green,
blue: components.blue,
alpha: components.alpha`

- Cannot convert value of type 'Double' to expected argument type 'CGFloat'. Replace 'components.red' with 'CGFloat(components.red)'

Comment: @TheAxolotlMan Ah, that could be because of a new Swift feature where that is implicitly converted. I have updated it to only use `CGFloat` now (I think, at least - quite difficult to know when it's implicit if I missed anything)

Comment: Cool, ill check again

Comment: Thanks so much! Now that is all working but the usage command is giving me these 3 errors

`Cannot call value of non-function type 'CGColor.Components?'

Consecutive declarations on a line must be separated by ';'

Expected declaration`

I'm new to Xcode so I have no idea. Can you tell me why this is happening?

Comment: @TheAxolotlMan It should work. The error can easily be found online. Basically, it means you may accidentally have something like `()` on the end if the `if let ...` line. It says you are trying to call it like a function.