# Export NSColor to JSON and preserve system colorspace/vibrancy for current mode

Tags: json, swift, nscolor

I have a **macOS**/`Swift` app that I have written a preferences tabview.  The preferences are being stored in `UserDefaults`.  I have implemented a `JSON` export routine to export the preferences.  I was using `sRGBA` values to store them as a `String`, but that does not correctly set the `NSColor` for the current appearance setting/vibrancy upon import.  When I import the `JSON` the colors are wrong.

I would like to know the best way to encode `NSColor` to data for export to `JSON` and then decode upon import.  This export/import method needs to preserve the actual color based on the current appearance/vibrancy when the export occurs.

I use an `NSColorWell` for the user to choose their color for a preference.  However, I am now thinking that in order to preserve the correct color for the current appearance, I would need to restrict them to a color pallet that only represents `"system"` colors for the specific preferences that would be affected by an appearance change.  Is that correct?  I can do that, but I don't know how to preserve that in a `JSON` export.

I am assuming that a proper **"system"** color import from `JSON` would allow the OS/App to correctly display the color based on the currently set appearance.  For example, if the user exported the preferences to JSON and the appearance at export time is **"Light"**, but when they do an import of those preferences, and the appearance has been changed to **"Dark"** the colors would update accordingly. Or would I need to reload the view to pick up the new colors for the current appearance?

I'm sure I can answer the above questions if I can figure out how to preserve the correct color setting for a `JSON` export/import.  I've tried going down the road to make `NSColor` `Codable`, but I'm having trouble with that as well.  I'll keep working in that direction until I find another way.

Comment: [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68719603/9223839) should be helpful

Comment: Yes, I came across that answer, but it is working with CGColor and not NSColor.  Anytime I convert NSColor to it's RGBA components and then re-import/decode those components, something is being lost because the color is different.  Even if I don't change the appearance, the imported color is not the same as .systemPurple, for example.

Comment: That's strange since there is an init for NSColor that takes a CGColor.

Comment: Well, after your comment, I went back stepped through my code line by line in the debug console and sure enough I found a math problem.  So, I guess I can stick to the current method for now and see how it works.