# Facing problems in converting SwiftUI Color to UIColor to save in user defaults

Tags: swift, swiftui, uicolor, userdefaults

I am trying to save a SwiftUI `Color` instance to user defaults. My understanding of the process is to first convert the `Color` instance to `UIColor`, then use `NSKeyedArchiver` to convert it to `Data`, which can be saved in user defaults. The process to read a value back would be the reverse of the above.

I tried this but was not getting correct results, so I wrote the following code, just to test the conversion from `Color` to `UIColor` and back:

```
let color = Color.orange
let uiColor = UIColor(color)
let convertedColor = Color(uiColor)
print(color == convertedColor)
```

The above code prints `false`, which means the two `Color` instances are not equal. Not sure why that is, since I have just converted the `Color` instance to `UIColor` and back. Is there some loss of information during the conversion? If yes, then how can a `Color` instance be saved to user defaults and correctly read back? Thanks.

Comment: "Is there some loss of information during the conversion?" I'm not sure, but I think it's something to do with dark mode. If you `print(convertedColor)` the result is a `UIDynamicProviderColor`.

Comment: I recommend converting the color to hex, then saving to UserDefaults.

Comment: Checking the equality of two `Color` structures is trickier than it seems, because comparing floats is tricky. `Color` is Equatable, but when it compares the RGB components which are Double converted to CGFloat (I believe for UIColor) converted back to Double could cause the bit representation of that float to look different and return something unequal, even though the numbers are, practically speaking, very close.  Not to mention you have other issues to consider like preserving the color-space (particularly with converting and comparing greys). Per @aheze,  just store the hex components?

Comment: This article shows one way to store and retrieve UIColor to UserDefaults:
https://betterprogramming.pub/save-uicolor-with-userdefaults-in-swift-5-951ef1aa88e8

There are also a number of ways to convert Color to hex and back, this is my take:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679658/swift-5-4-hex-to-nscolor/68680901#68680901