# Label text colour not changing to custom added colour

Tags: ios, swift, text, colors, uilabel

I need to add a text colour to a programatically added label. I have a hex color which i need to assign to my label text. I am not able to see the custom added color to the text. I have added same code to one of my views background color and it works for that view. Please help.

Note: self.colorSelected has hex string

```
let labelTextView: UILabel = {
                let labelView = CustomLabelForTextView()
                labelView.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                labelView.font = UIFont(name: "Avenir-Medium", size: 20.0)
                
                if UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "colorSelectedForText") == true {
                    let selectedColor = self.colorSelected
                    let color = UIColor(hex: selectedColor)
                    labelView.textColor = .some(color!)
                }else {
                    labelView.textColor = .darkGray
                }
                labelView.text = “”Hello World
                labelView.backgroundColor = .clear
                return labelView
            }()
      View1.addSubview(labelTextView)
            
            labelTextView.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.centerXAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
            labelTextView.centerYAnchor.constraint(equalTo: View1.centerYAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
                        labelTextView.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 50).isActive = true
                        labelTextView.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 30).isActive = true
```

This is the extension for UIColor i am using (got it on stackoverflow)-

```
extension UIColor {
    public convenience init?(hex: String) {
        let r, g, b, a: CGFloat

        if hex.hasPrefix("#") {
            let start = hex.index(hex.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)
            let hexColor = String(hex[start...])

            if hexColor.count == 8 {
                let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
                var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0

                if scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
                    r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff000000) >> 24) / 255
                    g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff0000) >> 16) / 255
                    b = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x0000ff00) >> 8) / 255
                    a = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x000000ff) / 255

                    self.init(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: a)
                    return
                }
            }
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Comment: are you sure `UserDefaults.standard.bool(forKey: "colorSelectedForText")` is true? Try adding print to see what `r`, `g, `b`, `a` are before return

Comment: also have a look at "my take" of getting color from hex: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679658/swift-5-4-hex-to-nscolor/68680901#68680901

Comment: @PhilipDukhov yes the value is true, all the variables have all the correct values but still it is not showing on the text

Comment: @PhilipDukhov func hexStringToUIColor(hex:String) -> UIColor {var cString:String = hex.trimmingCharacters(in: .whitespacesAndNewlines).uppercased()
 if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {cString.remove(at: cString.startIndex)}
 if ((cString.count) != 6) {return UIColor.gray}
 var rgbValue:UInt64 = 0
 Scanner(string: cString).scanHexInt64(&rgbValue)
 return UIColor(red: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0xFF0000) >> 16) / 255.0,green: CGFloat((rgbValue & 0x00FF00) >> 8) / 255.0,blue: CGFloat(rgbValue & 0x0000FF) / 255.0,alpha: CGFloat(1.0))} I am using this code to convert Hex to UIColor. Still not working

Comment: can you show an example of what you have in  "selectedColor". My simple test with your hex code did not work for me. However, it works well with my code at the link I posted.

Comment: a few more tests, and I see that your UIColor hex code does not work for me at all. Try my code and tell us if that works for you.

Comment: @workingdog I tried your code for UIColor, but its still not working for my labelView.textColor . I am assigning it in this way "labelView.textColor = .some(ncolor)" where n color is the rgb value that we get. Please let me know if I am assigning it incorrectly

Comment: labelView.textColor takes a UIColor, so you need to use `labelView.textColor = color`  where color, as in your code is a UIColor that you get from using the hex string.

Comment: @workingdog , Tried -  labelView.textColor = nscolor , no luck, could you please share me a code you tried that gave the required output

Comment: there is no nscolor in the code you are showing us. There is `let color = UIColor(hex: selectedColor)` use that color in `labelView.textColor = color`, not nscolor with the rgb values as you mentioned. Make sure `selectedColor` represent some valid hex color string, like `#d2f943`

Answer (score 0):

Just try your colour setting code inside main thread.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    
    let color = UIColor(hex: selectedColor)
    labelView.textColor = color
    
}
```

This happened to me while setting label text colour inside the table view cell. And I resolved it by setting text colour inside the main thread.