# SwiftUI ColorPicker with binding to hex string causes large drift

Tags: swift, swiftui, colors, hex, nscolor

The codebase I am working with (https://github.com/utmapp/UTM) stores configuration as a plist, so a Color value can't be saved as-is.

The method I'm trying to implement now is by having extension methods on `NSColor` to convert to/from a hex string, and wrapping that in a Binding for a SwiftUI `ColorPicker`.

The problem is that when changing the selected color in the picker's wheel, there is quite a lot of "drift" (the brightness will move when I change the color, and the color moves seemingly randomly when I move the brightness back up).

Here's the code I'm using for testing (meant to be put in an Xcode Swift Playground):

```swift
import SwiftUI
import PlaygroundSupport

struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var colorHex = "#FFFFFF"
    
    private var colorBinding: Binding<Color> {
        Binding<Color> {
            Color(NSColor(hexString: colorHex)!)
        } set: { newValue in
            colorHex = NSColor(newValue).hexString!
        }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            colorBinding.wrappedValue
            
            ColorPicker("Pick a color", selection: colorBinding, supportsOpacity: true).padding()
        }
    }
}


extension NSColor {
    var hexString: String? {
        guard let rgbColor = self.usingColorSpace(.sRGB) else {
            return nil
        }
        let red = Int(rgbColor.redComponent * 255)
        let green = Int(rgbColor.greenComponent * 255)
        let blue = Int(rgbColor.blueComponent * 255)
        return String(format: "#%02X%02X%02X", red, green, blue)
    }
    
    convenience init?(hexString hex: String) {
        if hex.count != 7 { // The '#' included
            return nil
        }
            
        let hexColor = String(hex.dropFirst())
        
        let scanner = Scanner(string: hexColor)
        var hexNumber: UInt64 = 0
        
        if !scanner.scanHexInt64(&hexNumber) {
            return nil
        }
        
        let r = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0xff0000) >> 16) / 255
        let g = CGFloat((hexNumber & 0x00ff00) >> 8) / 255
        let b = CGFloat(hexNumber & 0x0000ff) / 255
        
        self.init(srgbRed: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1)
    }
}

PlaygroundPage.current.setLiveView(ContentView())
```

Comment: you could have a look at this SO post/answer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679658/swift-5-4-hex-to-nscolor/68680901#68680901

Comment: @workingdog The only difference I can see in that answer is using `lroundf` and `%02lX` in the format string. I tried doing that on my code and there's still a drift. If there's something different that I didn't notice, please help to bring it to my attention. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was having exact the same problem and was able to solve it by changing the  colorspace in the Color initializer from .sGRB to .displayP3.

The hint for me was that the ColorPicker at the slider Tab was showing something like "Display P3 Hex-Colorcode".

Comment: Thanks! In the end, I didn't implement it (the main dev did), and looking at the code now, other than some code style changes, it's essential my original code, but using displayP3 instead of sRGB.