# Get Hex Value Of Color SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui

I could not find a way to get the hex code value of a `Color` in SwiftUi, anyone wanna post it here so that people can Google it and find it? And also to help me?

By the way, I am using a color picker, assigning the value to a `Color` and need to get the hex value.

Another reason this is hard to find is because when Googling it, I only get Hex to Color, not Color to Hex, and I am a very good Googler.

Good day/night, person.

Comment: I even had a go myself, a long time ago, here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68679658/swift-5-4-hex-to-nscolor/68680901#68680901